# Ground loops with S/FTP Cat6 Ethernet cables

Tags: ethernet, ground-loop

I have an issue with an Ethernet cable causing a ground loop between my router and a raspberry pi, causing noise on the ground of the DC power of the Raspberry. The router/power supply of the RPi are plugged into different wall sockets.

Since to my knowledge Ethernet itself is decoupled, I assume it is the shielding of the Ethernet cable that causes the problem.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: Why do you think the cause is a ground loop? Ground loops are very specific in producing low frequency AC power frequency noise so I'm interested in how you went from "symptoms" to "wiring problem".

Comment: Plugging in the ethernet cable causes significant 50Hz noise to appear on a laser error signal that shares ground with the RPi

Comment: Unplug all the gear from power and see if the Ethernet cable is actually creating a path of continuity between signals beyond the magnetics.  It should not be, if it is those seem somehow bypassed.  Don't rule out some periodic data/software behavior linked to the existence of the network.  If you line trigger a scope can you see that the noise is mains locked?

Comment: Most Ethernet cable is UTP - Unshielded Twisted Pair, containing 8 wires and no cable shield. Are you using STP - Shielded Twisted Pair cable?

Comment: According to the https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/116d/0900766b8116ddc5.pdf datasheet it is shielded

Comment: @ChrisStratton I did not linetrigger it, but it is a sinusoidal 50Hz signal appearing on the scope, immediately appearing/disappearing with plugging in the cable

Comment: It *is* shielded... *double*-shielded: `Construction: 4-pair stranded copper wire. Complete braid shielding. Pairs shielded with aluminium clad polyester foil.`  That's one awesome cable. I bet the noise would go away if a cheap (UTP) cable were used... however it might be slightly more susceptible to data corruption.

Comment: Please determine if each supply is 2 or 3 pin and if reversible, try that on one.   Leakage currents can setup a CM noise issue rather than a ground loop issue.  When the DC power is floating and not earth grounded then floating leakage currents may occur.  If you can earth ground at either end to 0Vdc , test that as well.  You may have STP cable but possibly not grounded to a common ground such as earth.

Comment: @Whitecold what kind of noise do you see?

Comment: What kind of power supplies do the RPI and router have? Indeed shielded CAT cables do connect the metal connector shells together, and these are either capacitively or sometimes directly connected to device ground. If the RPI power supply has a EMI capacitor inside it between primary and secondary, it would indeed cause a ground loop.

Comment: @VoltageSpike The noise is a sinusoidal modulation at 50Hz

Comment: @Whitecold have you tried unshieled UTP?

Comment: The router uses the power supply provided by the manufacturer (NETGEAR). The RPi draws from a low noise DC lab power supply. The DC ground is not floating, but grounded to the AC ground via some device casings. I don't know how the router is grounded.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I unfortunately don't have a 20m unshielded cable around.

Comment: @Whitecold did you come to any conclusion on this at the end?

Comment: I found a medical ethernet isolator around which decoupled the shielding.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a shielded cable?
Cut the shield at the raspberry pi end?
Put a 10 ohm resistor in the shield at the raspberry pi end?
Make a cat 6 isolation transformer?

Mostly stolen from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_%28electricity%29#Solutions)